# How to programatically find the external IP address of a Google Cluster created with Dataproc?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataproc

When I create a Compute cluster using Google's Dataproc, if the cluster name is "MyCluster" in project, "MyProject-107701" then the master cluster is recognized internally as "mycluster-m.c.myproject-107701.internal" (Not sure where the ".c" comes from, but it's what is revealed from using nslookup). Doing an nslookup on "mycluster-m" reveals the internal ip, but not the external ip.

I can see the external id on the VMs page of the console. However, I am not sure how to obtain this programatically (using Java - short of scraping html pages).

I want to be able to create a cluster, return the ip address to an external process, which will then connect, but will not want to connect using gsutil. How would I do this? Is it possible to obtain the external ip address through the Dataproc Java APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible through a combination of two APIs. The first call to make is to the Dataproc API to obtain a definitive list of master nodes for a cluster. This can be done with [clusters.get](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters/get), and extracting a master-node name from [cluster.config.masterConfig.instanceNames](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters#InstanceGroupConfig).

Once you have a master name instance name you can use the Compute Engine API to [get the GCE Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/get) and from the GCE instance, you can extract [networkInterfaces[0].accessConfig.natIP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances#resource).

Comment: Thanks, Angus. By any chance, is there a corresponding java library for this call? The page references code that invokes new Compute.Builder. I would have thought to have found that method here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-compute/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/compute/Compute.java, but I did not see it. Is this the right java library? (perhaps I am missing something, or else some docs out of date?)

Comment: Compute.Builder is a reference to the auto-generated libraries available from maven central (compute): http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.apis%7Cgoogle-api-services-compute%7Cv1-rev131-1.22.0%7Cjar and dataproc: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.apis%7Cgoogle-api-services-dataproc%7Cv1-rev10-1.22.0%7Cjar

Comment: Alright, I used the library from github, that I referenced earlier. The code might be somewhat different from the docs presented on the page, but it seems that the functionality is the same. I have a blocking issue that is unrelated, so I cannot confirm my fix yet, but when I do, if it works, I will mark this answer as accepted.